# How to remove the port number in the url for nginx reverse proxy rule

Tags: nginx

I've two domains(site1.com, site2.com) running on a single server, site1 is running on port 80 of the server itself while site2 running on port 8082 based on a wordpress docker image. The docker is started using the command:

```
docker run --privileged -itd --name wordpress2 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wp2 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=pass -p 8082:80 --link mysql:mysql wordpress
```

As site1.com already occupy 80 port and I can't ask user to visit site2.com specifying 8082 port number, so I set nginx proxy_pass rule like below:

```
server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.site2.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }
    }
```

But it still jump to 8082 port when I enter the url as http://www.site2.com in chrome, here is the curl result.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 24 Aug 2019 09:29:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.7
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ea2c8aa5c9dfbf79046440cc8f66d35e; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Location: http://www.site2.com:8082/
```

could anybody please help to explain what's the reason and how to make it act as normal website?

==========================

solved, just forgot to change wordpress SITEURL and HOME settings, thank RichardSmith again for the kindly help!

Comment: Try adding: `proxy_redirect http://www.site2.com:8082/ /;`

Comment: @RichardSmith, it does not work, I added proxy_redirect after my proxy_pass and got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS exception, seems proxy_redirect redirect requests back repeatedly.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
    Server: nginx  
    Date: Sat, 24 Aug 2019 12:53:52 GMT  
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
    Location: http://www.xxxx.com/  
    Connection: keep-alive  
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.7  
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2171eca671f8ad2a9df3c19dd81765ed; path=/  
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate  
    Pragma: no-cache  
    X-Redirect-By: WordPress

Comment: The `proxy_redirect` rule answers your question, but the question should be why is WordPress redirecting in the first place. Have you set the SITEURL and HOME for the WordPress site to the actual domain name?

Comment: Yeah, it's really the wordpress setting problem, I forgot to change it, it works now, thank you very much for notifying me this!!!